# Get gmail email using django allAuth

Tags: django, gmail, django-allauth

I'm new to that Auth things so I have a problem. I've connected allAuth to my django application, with "socialaccount.providers.google", I created google application, authorized through it and now I want request the list of my incoming emails from Gmail, and I really can't understand where to put all those secret keys and tokens in the request.

P.S. Sorry for such a dumb question.

Comment: *now I need to request my emails from Gmail* is not very clear.. You should edit your question to explain this -- do you want to access the contents of some email messages? Do you want email addresses for authorized users to your app? etc.  Also it's not clear from your question how far you got or what specifically you need help with.

Comment: Agree, thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

It's old question without views and activity, but for some reason I found it quickly while googling. I think it can be helpful for someone.

First of all: you need to use server-side flow and you need OAuth 2 Clien ID with type "Web Application" (but it depends).
With server-side flow, you have to exchange google's auth code with access/refresh tokens on your server.

It's a basic django-allauth conf to do what you want:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'offline',  # to request refresh_token from Google 
        }
    }
}
```

Then basic logic to get API service (aka API client):

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialToken, SocialApp
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def get_gmail_service(token: SocialToken):
    # SocialToken.token_secret is a refresh token in case of Google
    assert token.token_secret, 'Can not use SocialToken without refresh token!'

    google_app = SocialApp.objects.filter(provider='google').first()
    assert google_app, 'Must create SocialApp for google provider first!'

    # this is simple example, but you need to use some credentials storage 
    # instead of SocialToken or manage how to sync creads data to SocialToken
    credentials = Credentials(
         token=token.token,
         refresh_token=token.token_secret,
         token_uri='https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
         client_id=google_app.client_id,
         client_secret=google_app.secret)

    return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

To test your service:

```
service = get_gmail_service(SocialToken.objects.first())
try:
    res = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=1).execute()
except HttpError as err:
    print('GMAIL ACCESS CHECK ERROR:', err)
else:
    print('GMAIL SUCCESS!')
```